# set ip default outgoing in centos

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ip, route

I have server which has `Centos` and I want to change the outgoing IP address.

This is the output of my `route` and `route list` commands.

```
[root@marketport tmp]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
184.105.17.96 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.224 U 0 0 0 venet0
162.245.223.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 venet0
169.254.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 1002 0 0 venet0
0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 U 0 0 0 venet0

[root@marketport tmp]# ip route list
184.105.17.96/27 dev venet0 proto kernel scope link src 184.105.17.106
162.245.223.0/24 dev venet0 proto kernel scope link src 162.245.223.65
169.254.0.0/16 dev venet0 scope link metric 1002
default dev venet0 scope link
```

I tried the below commands.

```
[root@marketport tmp]# ip route add default via 162.245.223.0 dev venet0 src 162.245.223.67
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument

[root@marketport tmp]# ip route add default via 162.245.223.67
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
```

But I got the error as `Invalid argument` and `File exists` as seen above. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You're only able to have 1 default route, so you need to delete it before you can change it to something else. I'd try something like this:

```
$ sudo ip route del default 
$ sudo ip route add default via 162.245.223.67
```

If you don't want to delete the default route you can also use the `ip route` sub-command `change` instead to change the route, which will allow for active connections to persist.

```
$ sudo ip route change default via 162.245.223.67
```

Comment: `ip route change default via 162.245.223.67` will also change the default route without the fear of dropping an ssh connection.

Comment: i was execute command successfully. and here is my ip route list 
184.105.17.96/27 dev venet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 184.105.17.106
162.245.223.0/24 dev venet0  proto kernel  scope link  src 162.245.223.65
169.254.0.0/16 dev venet0  scope link  metric 1002
default via 162.245.223.67 dev venet0
how can i verify outgoing my ip is 162.245.223.67?

Comment: +1 for ip route change default as a non-destructive way

Comment: @user3138338 - can you add that output to the Q? I can't follow if it worked or not.

Comment: @user3138338 verify your external IP by running `curl ifconfig.me`